# How to evaluate pairwise error probability and detection in presence of gaussian noise?

Tags: digital-communications, noise, signal-detection, gaussian

I am reading Digital Communication Systems by Simon Haykin and I am stuck at one point.

Consider a two-dimensional signal space that has a message constellation of four points, given by $s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4$. We need to calculate pairwise error probability in the presence of additive white Gaussian noise ($w$). The signal vectors are arranged so as to be aligned with the basis vectors, as shown in the figure

[image: figure1]

The observed vector $x$ is given as
$$x=s_1+w$$
where $s_1$ is the transmitted message.
We can calculate the probability of error using $\int_{Z_j} f_x(x|s_i)dx$ where $j\neq i$ and $Z$ is the observation space which is divided into various small $Z_i$'s for detection purposes. Assuming variance of noise to be $N_0/2$, we can write the error as:
$$\int_{Z_j}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi N_0}}\exp(-(x-s_1)^2/N_0) dx$$
As shown in the figure

[image: fig]

we take the bisector and define the distance between $s_1$ and $s_4$ as $d_{14}$, which gives the pairwise probability expression as:
$$\int_{d_{14}/2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi N_0}}\exp(-v^2/N_0) dv$$ where $d_{14}$ is the distance between constellation points $s_1$ and $s_4$
However, my confusion is what if we exceed the limit $d_{14}/2$ in another location as shown in the figure

[image: fig]

As Euclidean distance is always positive, does the expression still hold?
**Please note I know that detection is going to work as the distance between $x$ and $s_1$ is smaller than between $x$ and $s_4$, but I am more concerned about this integral expression, how does it work here?**
$$\int_{d_{14}/2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi N_0}}\exp(-v^2/N_0) dv$$
because the distance is greater than $d_{14}/2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the book carefully, you will notice and understand that the probability given by the equation

$$\int_{d_{14}/2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi N_0}}\exp(-v^2/N_0) dv$$

is the **error probability** for the event that the received signal ***x is closer to*** $s_k$ ***than*** $s_i$, ***when*** $s_i$ ***is sent***. In your figure, it is the error probability that $x$ is closer to $s_4$ than $s_1$ when $s_1$ is sent, or $x$ is closer to $s_1$ than $s_4$ when $s_4$ is sent.

The situation which makes you confused is a different situation, in which $x$ is closer to $s_1$ than $s_4$ when $s_1$ is sent. This situation does not create an error decision, and makes no contribution to the error probability.

Comment: The other thing not being taken into account is the decision boundaries.  For the four points show and zero mean, symmetric noise, I believe the decision boundaries will be the lines $y=x$ and $y=-x$.  The given integral formula for the error is only applicable if the measurement point $x$ is on the line between $s_1$ and $s_4$.  If it's not, $x$ may be closer to $s_2$ or $s_3$.

Comment: @Peter K. Please note we are talking about pairwise error probabilities here and therefore, the decision boundary is just between two signal points and not more than that.

Comment: @Userhanu OK. Seems like a toy problem, though, that could have been done with just two signal points $s_1$ and $s_2$.